# Multi Keyword search in SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, keyword

I have 3 fields: LastName, MRnumber and SSN. All 3 are part of a patient record. Now the user can search by 1 ,2 or all 3 keywords. The MRnumber or SSN are unique and each of them will retrieve one unique record. However these values are not always present. For example the patient did not want to give his SSN. Keeping in mind that there would be a lot of records, which is the best way to do this? I'm using MS Access and Delphi as front (if it matters).

Comment: Thank you for the edit..it is 1 am.. Im tired.

Comment: It is not clear what behaviour should be implicated by the following: *‘The MRnumber or SSN are unique and each of them will retrieve one unique record. However these values are not always present.’* If, for instance, the user entered both MRNumber and SSN in the search fields, would you like them `and`ed or `or`ed in your query? Could you just add examples illustrating various combinations of data in your DB and search terms entered, and then show what the results must be in each case? And last but not least: **[what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Answer (score 1):

In interpret your question as follows:

Each record has
Lastname, not unique, always present
MRNumber, unique, optional
SSN, unique, optional

You search on (LastName and MRNumber) of (Lastname and SSN) or (Lastname and MRNumber and SSN)

But since MRNumber and SSN are both unique the last search is superfluous.

You don't tell use what components you're using so only a generic answer is possible.
Assuming that your Delphi app does some pre-processing, I'd do:

```
If MRNumber given
  search on (LastName and MRNumber)
else
  If SSN given
    search on (LastName and SSN)
  else
    message(Insufficient data)
```

Comment: Ok so you would check each individual field..I was thinking that there might be a simpler SQL statement. I came down to 3 possible ways of doing this:
A) 3 input fields each one with its own search button.
B) Combo box, called search by, and let the user pick:
C) 3 input fields and I would grade the searches. 
Thank you I think I would use the combo box..it may be more elegant way of doing it and simpler to code.
Thnx again.

Comment: Im still curious however : say you have the following search options: First Name, Age and Gender as separate txt fields and a single search button..how would you construct the query ? The user may use all of the search fields to retrieve a single record or use combinations to retrieve multiple records ? In other words the more search words you use the more specific you become in  your search.

Comment: If it gets really complex I would build up the SQL statement in code: SELECT... FROM... WHERE and then add conditions based on what the user selected/filled in. Then put the statement in your query component and execute.